# servicestack fields sometimes retain values in a view used for editing and creating new entity

Tags: servicestack

i have a screen (view) which i use to list all instances of an entity in a table. if i double-click on a row, i am taken to a screen where i can edit that entity.

there is a button on the list screen which if clicked, takes me to the same view used for edits, but this time with empty fields, for creating a new instance of the entity.

sometimes(!), if i have edited and saved an entity, returned to the list and clicked the "new" button, when i am taken to the screen for creating a new entity, it has values populated from the entity i have just been editing. is there anything in servicestack that might cause this 'leakage' of data?

many thanks.

EDIT: should say that this is a servicestack.razor (the new api) implementation with c#, with no use of mvc at all.

Comment: Any chance you can create a stand-alone prototype that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: hi - thanks for your reply. it would be quite difficult to take any kind of vertical slice through the application. if i could manage to disentangle something, what should i do with it?

Comment: If you can post a link to a GitHub repo, that would be ideal. All I'd need is a small project that reproduces the unintended behavior.

Comment: hi - i have put up a zipped solution here

http://www.podsol.co.uk/servicestack/sstest.zip

this has the observed behaviour. there is a sql script in the sql folder. run this to create the small test d/base. many thanks

Comment: Can't open it in VS 2010, is this a VS 2012 sln? I don't have this at home, will look at it at work once I find the free time.

Comment: Sorry but your sample project is unusable, I've given up trying to get it to do anything.

Comment: ? don't understand. it's a simple demo. i'm actually using it right now to see if i can see what might be causing this problem. did you create the database?

Comment: I did, but I couldn't create any data/rows in the database with your UI.

Comment: no, there is no facility for doing that in the sample. just go into the database manually and stick some data in ( a couple of rows will do) using sql server management studio. 

the problem i'm seeing is to do with data retrieval, not data entry

Comment: i realise you'll be a busy man. if you could point me to the relevant dll (and hence source code) i'd be happy to have a look at this myself. it is a bit of a showstopper for me and i'm hoping it's just not the case that i'm doing something silly in my own code...

Comment: All source code is in https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ Here's the src for the [Razor Project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Razor), the Razor plugin starts from the RazorFormat class.

Comment: well....thanks! i am in the process of porting a large commercial application over from mvc4/web api/entity framework to servicestack. this has so far put me back probably 3 weeks. if this proves to be a fatal flaw in servicestack, then i guess the decision will be taken to stop the port - that would be a pity because this far, ss has been quite good to work with. i'll give it a couple of days and report back to my bosses on how it's going. they won't want me to get bogged down in a framework, when the existing mvc platform does the job. anyway....thanks for all your help in this so far...

Comment: ok, the problem seems to be the template caching. it seems to be caching the values which are put into fields and then retrieves these the next time the template is accessed.

Comment: From your project, what's an example of the fields and template that's getting cached?

Comment: name and field1 are getting cached. 

it seems to be happening in the 

public IRazorTemplate ExecuteTemplate<T> method, ln 30:

instance.Execute();

the templateCache seems to get updated with the template along with data at that point. would that make sense?

Comment: it is the 'test' template, along with data, that is being cached. this seems to happen when you double-click a row in the table to see the item details.

Comment: def. something strange going on with caching. after instance.Execute(); all templateCache entries get the same value. is there any way to see what is going on inside Execute()? i can't see any implementation?

Comment: i think i've struggled with this long enough. either i am doing something very silly or there is something intrinsically wrong at the heart of this framework. either way, it is proving to be an intensely frustrating experience. all due credit to the guys who have taken it this far, and i realise that it is unpaid. but if, as i think i picked up somplace, you are wanting to go commercial with it, then i think it needs looking at in detail. if it can't handle something as simple as this current scenario, i can only suggest it is currently unfit for purpose.

Comment: As soon as we can repro the error we can fix it. Feel free to submit a **reproducible, stand-alone failing test** (you can use a stand-alone HttpListener host if it makes it easier) either as a pull request or linked to a gist on the [GitHub issuses](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues). I'm sorry you weren't able to debug your issue with the source code, that doesn't mean everything you can't do is unfit for purpose.

Comment: the project i indicated highlights the issue perfectly. i'm not sure what more you'd need. at the risk of repeating myself,

Comment: Your project doesn't even work, let alone go deep enough to repro the issue. We need something that's isolated, i.e. without any extra cruft, that actually works (in the state it was sent), that we can run, that shows the failed assertion of what you expected to happen vs what actually happens. This is far from perfect, it ended up being a time sink, where I was no closer in learning about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i thought that the project i indicated highlights the issue perfectly. i'm not sure what more you'd need. at the risk of repeating myself,

1. with a couple of rows of data in the d/base, load up the data in the listings page. this shows a table of the data.
2. double click on a row to produce a screen which has a form. the form is populated with the data from the row.
3. go back to the listings page.
4. now hit the "new" button. this produces the same view which was used to render the row you clicked on in step 2.
5. see that the form in the view is populated with the old data from the previous rendering, when in fact it should be empty because you want to use the form to create a new entity.

what seems to be happening is that the first time the view (form) is rendered, (are they not precompiled?) it is put into the cache. the problem is that any data which are in the form elements (textboxes etc) seems to be put into the cache as well. so, when you then use the view to try to create a new entity, and want all the fields to be empty, it is in fact pre-populated with the old data.

not sure how i can clearer be about this? or how a unit test would help? as i said, the project i put on the website shows this behaviour clearly. i'd be willing to spend more time on it, but i can't afford to wait the long delays between posting here and getting a response. again, i understand you're busy like the rest of us. it might help if you could answer the questions i'd had about how is it that the execute method populates the cache? or does it? the source code is not that clear to follow as there is very little inline documentation with it so i spent quite a bit of time stepping through with the debugger etc etc....and i'm still not clear about some things.

anyway, i apologise if i come across as complaining, don't mean to. the framework has great potential i'm sure.

Comment: and i think we should take this offline rather than clutter up stackoverflow?

Comment: I'll retry to repro after work, tonight if I have time otherwise tomorrow.

Comment: Ok it [should be fixed in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/cef8bb6d6b9d93041628b87140bc008c1454902e), just had to use a new instance of the HtmlHelper. I've already deployed this fix on ServiceStack.Razor v3.9.36 on NuGet so if you update it should be resolved.

Comment: fixed! many many thanks. that was a real showstopper for me but now we can continue with the porting. that's a beer i owe you! :)

Comment: Cool, tho when you have the free time, I'd settle for a blog post on ServiceStack instead :)